# Where should node and node_modules be installed on Centos 7?

Tags: node.js, npm, ghost

I am trying to install the Ghost blogging platform as a Node module on Centos 7 box.  My question is: ***Where should node, npm, and node_modules be installed, ideally?***

Currently, I have ghost installed in /var/www/ghost, and there are 50+ node modules in /var/www/ghost/node_modules/ (some of those modules have their own subdirectories called /node_modules/).

The Node binary itself is in /usr/local/bin, and *forever* and *npm* are in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.  /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/lib are owned by "500" (a system user?), and the files in /usr/local/... are owned by root.

However, I'm having all sorts of problems--As user A, ghost runs but forever fails, and the opposite happens as user B (forever works but ghost fails); NPM says I need to sudo; then when I use sudo it says "command npm not found;" Yarn fails, etc.

I'm guessing that I just have a tangle of permissions problems caused by installing modules in the wrong directories. The only complication is that I want Node to be installed system-wide but I want most of the processes to be run by unprivileged users:

- For security, the ghost processes should be run by an unprivileged user, and I think Node should be as well;
- I want to run ghost long-term using either *forever* or *pm2* (which are also Node modules), and they should also be run by an unprivileged user;
- Node must be installed system-wide (the Ghost installation documents say: "*Ghost requires a system-wide installation.  It is not enough to symlink the local installation to /usr/bin/node*," and they strongly recommend against using NVM).  I don't know if it's relevant, but I plan to do future non-Ghost projects (Node/Express/D3, etc.) based on the same Node installation.
- I need to be able to update everything with NPM or Yarn.

Comment: I would use a version manager such as nvm (https://github.com/creationix/nvm). This will install Node versions in `/home/user/.nvm` and will install Node modules alongside the respective Node versions. This approach should untangle all of your permissions issues and make Node available system-wide to unprivileged users. Here's a helpful guide: https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-multiple-versions-node-nvm/

Comment: The Ghost documentation says "If you installed node via nvm, we highly recommend that you uninstall nvm. Several people have run into permission problems because they've installed nvm in /root or /home, which is a local installation of node. Ghost requires a system wide installation."  Let's say I'm user A, but I want to run ghost as unprivileged user B: if I put Node in /home/A, wouldn't that make it inaccessible to user B?